# Checking an array if it has allowed or disallowed characters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add the feature of notallowedcharacters into my function check how would I do this?

```
var userinput = prompt('Input characters:');

var lowercase = userinput.toLowerCase();

var allowedcharacters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

var notallowedcharacters = ["g-z"] && ["!","@","#","€","£","$","%","&","?","*","/","\","|",";",":","<",">","[","]","{","-","_","^","~","`","±","§"]

function match(input, statement) {
    for (var i = 0; i < statement.length; i++) {
        if (input.indexOf(statement[i]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if (match(lowercase, allowedcharacters)){
  alert(true);
}
else{
  alert(false);
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% what you tried to achieve in the line `var notallowedcharacters = ...;`, but the boolean AND operator `&&` won't merge arrays. It will simply return the operand that determines the outcome of the operation, in this case the second array.

Comment: @FelixKling in the var notallowedcharacters I want made a list of all the characters that if the user inputed these it would return with false

Comment: You can use `var a = [], b = []; a.concat(b)` to merge arrays. Though I'd better go for regexp solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is use Regular Expressions to check for strings, characters, patterns that you want to mark as illegal in your function.

There are plenty of examples and explanations of that in the Mozilla Documents and on the web in general on how to construct the expressions, which can be as complex as you can imagine, should you need, which is why they are the de facto standard for this type of thing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

This for example catches mismatched telephone numbers which can be extrapolated to your use case.

```
<button onclick="testInfo(document.getElementById('phone'));">Check</button>

var re = /(?:\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))([-\/\.])\d{3}\1\d{4}/;  // RegEx Pattern
function testInfo(phoneInput){  
    var OK = re.exec(phoneInput.value);  
    if (!OK)  
      window.alert(RegExp.input + " isn't a phone number with area code!");  
    else
      window.alert("Thanks, your phone number is " + OK[0]);  
}
```